# How to add language in Localization?

Tags: ios, xcode

I was looking at the localization inside Info of the Project, but I was unable to zh-CN or zh-TW for simplified and traditional Chinese respectively.

Is it possible to add languages to the localization of the Project?

[image: For Reference]

Comment: zh-CN and zh-TW is ***not*** simplified and traditional Chinese respectively. You should use zh-Hans and zh-Hant.

Comment: Actually my question is whether I can add a language with a certain code such as zh-CN and zh-TW because these codes are being used in the backend side of things.